# Media Queries for Ratio not triggering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to test some Ratio media queries:

For example:

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5) { ... }
```

See the full code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">

    .mq {
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 8/5) {

    .mq {
        background-color: red;
    }

}

  </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="mq">
    Some text here. This DIV can be resized.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem with the code above is that it was supposed to go red only when ratio is 18/5 but it's always Red.

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, the CSS says that you need a ratio of at least 8/5, if you drag the screen size around you should see it change when your window is much taller than it is wide.

If you want to have this effect for the div, not the window, then you'll need to handle that with javascript instead of a media query.

```
var $div = $('.mq');
$div.change(function() {
    if ($div.width() / $div.height() < 1.6) {
        $div.css('background-color', 'white')
    } else {
        $div.css('background-color', 'red')
    }
});
```

Comment: I can see it works but only when resizing the browser. I need it to change when the div is resized not the browser window

Comment: @max2020 that isn't something you can do w/ media queries. Sorry. You'll have to use a javascript solution for that. A media query is just based on the browser window, not any relationship of `<divs>` or content actually within the page.

Comment: Do you know of anything that I can use for this?

Comment: Use javascript, when the div is resized. I'll update my answer